# Testing if emacs was invoked with a file to visit

Tags: init-file

I'd like to configure emacs to enable `desktop-save-mode` at startup, but only if it is not invoked with a file to edit. That is, I want to use `desktop-save-mode` when I call `emacs`, but not when I call `emacs file.txt`. Originally, I considered just testing if `command-line-args` was empty, but this would also disable `desktop-save-mode` if I called emacs with flags for some other reasons, e.g. `emacs -nw`. I could try to write a script to parse the command line arguments myself, but that sounds tedious and error prone, so I'm hoping to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use variable `command-line-args` to obtain the list of command-line arguments passed to Emacs.  That will tell you whether a file name was passed as argument.

`C-h v command-line-args` tells you something like this:

> command-line-args is a variable defined in `C source code`.
>   Its value is
>
> `("C:\\my-emacs\\bin\\emacs.exe"
>   "c:\\some-file-or-directory-name")`
>
> Documentation:
>
> Args passed by shell to Emacs, as a list of strings.
>
> Many arguments are deleted from the list as they are processed.

Comment: Wouldn't `command-line-args` include _all_ tokens passed to the emacs executable, including other flags and such?

Comment: Yes. You would filter that list to remove args other names of files to visit (not load).